# Шахматы на android

Tags: java, android, разработка-игр

Пишу шахматы с простеньким (пока что) ИИ на java. Уже вся логика игры есть. Написал простенькую визуализацию на javafx, все нормально. Решил переписать на свой android и понял, что это волокита та еще. Я прошу помочь с написанием по большей части графики. Итак, что мне нужно:

1) У меня есть png всех фигур и доски тоже. Нужно чтобы доска была в центре по всей ширине экрана. При этом я должен знать ее верхний левый угол, **чтобы**

2) еще должен быть listener для нажатия по экрану и **с помощью координат угла доски** я определял какая клетка нажата (что-то типа i = (int) getX / CELL_SIZE)) для совершения хода player.move(x1,y1,x2,y2).

3) На доске должны быть фигурки. У меня уже есть метод player.move(). После него должны произойти обновления позиций. То есть я пробегаю forx(1...8) fory(1...8), получаю метод toString() фигуры на этой позиции (например получаю BLACK_BISHOP) и вас прошу помочь только чтобы на этой позиции выводилась png фигуры toString(). Ну и наверное, это должно с каждым ходом перерисовываться.

Использую android studio.

Comment: мб смотреть в сторону canvas? А еще лучше поискать туториал на английском

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удачность описанного движка вызывает некоторые сомнения... Но если работает, то это не по теме :)

Во первых очень надеюсь, что ваш движок абстрагирован от интерфейса, иначе придется править почти все...

Вам нужно в первую очередь определиться со способом управления. Либо вы используете drag & drop, либо первым тапом выделяете клетку с фигурой, вторым- клетку куда хотите эту фигуру переместить.

Если первый вариант, то вам придется делать примерно следующее:

- Создаем класс клетки, наследованный от `View`. Он должен знать какая он клетка(координаты), и в зависимости от координат определять свой цвет и закрашиваться им
- Основное поле содержит наследованный от `AbsoluteLayout`(мне кажется с ним получить
  квадратные клетки будет проще всего) элемент. В нем программно создаем 64 клетки, в методе `layout` определяем ширину нашей доски, вычисляем положение каждой клетки и передаем в нее, вызывая для каждой клетки ее `layout(l,t,r,b)`
- Создаем класс фигуры. Он должен знать что это за фигура и иметь ссылку на свою клетку. Из клетки он берет rigth, top, left, bottom и ставит себе себе такие же. Из типа фигуры - нужную картинку и отрисовывает внутри себя. Так мы получаем размеченное поле с фигурами на нем
- Фигурки учим передвигаться с помощью Drag & Drop. Он реализован в андроиде, гуглите

Если управляем только кликами, то действуем совсем иначе. Мне кажется проще будет создать одну единственную View, в которой в методе onDraw() мы отрисовываем и поле, и фигуры, и выделенные клетки в текущем состоянии.

Попробуйте податься в какой-то из вариантов, будут более конкретные вопросы - пишите

Пример для второго варианта

```
public class BoardView extends View {
    private int width = 0, height = 0;
    private float startx, starty, board_size;
    private Paint black = new Paint();
    private Paint white = new Paint();

    {
        black.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        white.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    }

    public BoardView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public BoardView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public BoardView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public void layout(int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        super.layout(l, t, r, b);
        //layout срабатывает, когда уже точно определено положение вьюшки
        //запоминаем в этот момент ширину и высоту
        width = r - l;
        height = b - t;
        //определяем размер доски в пикселях и координаты верхнего левого угла
        if (width > height) {
            starty = 0;
            startx = (width - height) / 2f;
            board_size = height;
        } else {
            startx = 0;
            starty = (height - width) / 2f;
            board_size = width;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        //рисуем черный квадрат во всю доску
        canvas.drawRect(startx, starty, startx + board_size, starty + board_size, black);
        //и теперь белые квадратики в шахматном порядке
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                if((i + j)%2 == 0)
                    continue;
                canvas.drawRect(
                        startx + i * board_size / 8f,
                        starty + j * board_size / 8f,
                        startx + (i + 1) * board_size / 8f,
                        starty + (j + 1) * board_size / 8f,
                        white);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Выберу второй вариант. А что насчет движка, то по мне он очень даже не плохой (знаю, не по теме, но): отдельный класс board с внешними методами move(), undo(), generateMoves(), есть абстр класс player, его имплементят классы human с просто методом move(cell1, cell2) и класс AI со своей логикой работы который и использует внешние методы класса board. Почему же сомнения, если не секрет?

Comment: Абстракность самой игры - хорошо. Мне не понравилось что тип фигуры определяется через парсинг строки. Подозреваю, что у вас есть объект для описания всех фигур, и в каждом методе куча if/switch для разделения поведения разных фигур. Много кода, тяжело читать, тяжело править, скорее всего много повторений какого-то кода...

Comment: Вот еще вопрос. Вот я создал класс GameView где будет прорисовка. Как мне уже в конструкторе этого класса узнать размеры экрана?

Comment: Есть метод layout. Перегрузите его, вызовите метод суперкласса и из пришедших в параметрах значений вычислите высоту и ширину

Comment: Как раз таки у меня помимо board есть абстр класс Piece от которого наследуются все фигуры, и в каждом классе фигуры описывается поведение этой фигуры и ее метод toString

Comment: Если для каждой фигуры свой класс, то все должно быть красиво, просто я не люблю сравнения строк, я бы тогда делал два поля - одно интовое с типом фигуры, второе булево с цветом

Comment: Можно пример layout пожалуйста? Я уже весь интернет перерыл и нашел только DisplayMetrics который работает только в MainActivity и метод onMeasure(w, h) который вызывается после конструктора. А мне нужно прямо в конструкторе поставить размер bitmap доски

Comment: В конструкторе вы этого никак не сможете сделать, т.к. пока не сработают onMeasure и layout, вьюшка имеет размеры 0:0. Сейчас набросаю пример

Comment: Добавил пример в ответ

Comment: Большое спасибо :)

Comment: Привет еще раз. Немного не по вопросу, но все же. Возникла небольшая проблема. В BoardView я могу прописать метод onTouch() для совершения хода игрока (допустим тут же я буду вызывать метод player.move() он обновит состояние игры ,но это уже не наша забота, и вызову invalidate() для отображения на экране. Но что если первый ход компьютера? Ведь я не захожу в метод onTouch() для него, но должен вызвать invalidate() после него.

Comment: так пусть вызовет invalidate :) Это самый обычный метод, который можно откуда угодно вызвать, главное View передать куда надо. То есть нужно передать игре либо интерфейс вызывающий invalidate, а игра будет вызывать метод интерфейса по мере надобности, или саму вьюшку отдать в игру и прусть она прям инвалидейт и вызывает

Comment: Вот еще что, для справки хотел узнать. Правильно ли я меняю черед хода игроков (я так и не нашел понятного кода)? Ход игрока я ловлю в вьюшке в методе onTouch (ибо я должен ждать нажатия игрока) и вызываю invalidate(), и после его обработки вызываю ход уже компьютера и invalidate(), и так далее.

Comment: Звучит благоразумно)